# I was building the code in CodeBuild,but getting error in UPLOAD_ARTIFACTS phase- "CLIENT_ERROR: no matching artifact paths found

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, devops, aws-codebuild, aws-codecommit

I was building the code in CodeBuild,but getting error in UPLOAD_ARTIFACTS phase-

```
CLIENT_ERROR: no matching artifact paths found".
while building the artifact file location is "/var/www/html/index.html.
```

The Build phase is successful but after build i was trying to change the artifact location to S3 bucket and after changing the location the build is not happening and getting error in UPLOAD_ARTIFACTS phase.

```
buildspec.yml file--
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    commands: 
      - echo installing NGINX
      - sudo apt-get update
      - sudo apt-get install nginx -y

  build:
    commands:
       - echo build started on 'date'
       - cp index.html /var/www/html/

  post_build:
     commands:
        - echo configuring NGINX

artifacts:
 files:
    -/var/www/html/index.html
```

I tried to build the code and store the artifact in S3 bucket.
I am expecting to solve the error `CLIENT_ERROR: no matching artifact paths found` so that while building i can store the artifact in S3 bucket.